# drop down menus keyboard accessiblity not working

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I am trying to make the menu bar keyboard accessible. I have replaced all the :hover with :focus. but still drop down menus are not coming through keyboard. 
Can anyone provide the solution...

thanks!!!

Comment: can you provide any codes? :/

Comment: Yes, any code, please. And please elaborate: are you testing with a screen reader or not? If so, which screen reader do you use?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the way that people quite often make dropdown menus happen I assume you are probably applying the :hover and :focus on a li element. This will work for :hover because in modern browsers all elements are able to use the :hover pseudo-class, but this will not work for :focus because by default only links and form controls (buttons, fields, etc) are able to use :focus.

You can force an element to accept :focus by using a tab-index, but this is pretty clunky for a menu so let's not do that.

The best bet, assuming my assumptions about your problem are correct, is to use a JS solution to make your dropdown keyboard accessible. I usually use a technique similar to this one, that applies the class of "hover" on the li elements are you access them (whether by the mouse or by the keyboard).

https://uablogs.missouri.edu/interface/2011/08/keyboard-accessible/